# Number of chords of a circle having natural length

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

In a circle of radius 17, point p lies on a distance 15 from center.How many distinct chords of this circle passing through p do have a natural length?
I tried to use the notion of Power of point relative to the circle and found the following chord segments:
$(2,32) (4,16) (8,8) (16,4) (32,2)$ , (these chords have lengths of $ 34,20$ etc.)
But it seems there must be more such chords! How??!!

Comment: Why did you use the power of the point? Do you want the two pieces of the chord (separated by the point $p$) to have integral length?

Comment: @almagest: I would guess "natural length" means a natural number, i.e. an integer

Comment: @almagest ,It was just an idea for solution.It's not required for the two segments to have integral lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a longest chord of length $2\times 17=34$ along the diameter through the point and a perpendicular shortest chord through the point of length  $2 \times \sqrt{17^2-15^2}=16$ and two chords of every intermediate length.

So the number of chords of integer length is $1+1+2\times (34-16-1)=36$

Comment: Please explain your formula

Comment: One for $34$, one for $16$ and two for every integer between them

Comment: How can you infer that ALL integers between 34 and 16 can be the lengths of such chords?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: The length of the chord is a continuous function of the angle of the chord, so it achieves all intermediate values at some angle.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The *longest possible* chord through $p$ is the diameter through it; the *shortest possible* chord is the one perpendicular to the diameter. If one or both of these are of integer length (the diameter surely is, having length $34$), they count for one each.

Every integer *between* those two limits is the length of exactly $2$ different chords.

(The mistake in your attempt seems to be that you're restricting yourself to chords where not only the length of the chord is an integer, but where $p$ divides it in two integral pieces -- which the problem doesn't appear to require. Also, your $2+32$ and $32+2$ solutions both denote the same chord, namely the diameter through $p$ seen from either one or the other end).

Comment: Is it a theorem( or something like that) that states : Every integer between those two limits is the length of exactly 2 different chords.

Comment: @Hamid: You can prove (using calculus) that the length of the chord is a decreasing function of the smaller of the angles it makes with the diameter.

Comment: Dear Henning, I wish I could accept more than 1 answer,as your answer is quite convincing

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers do not explain why every chord length between the longest and shortest chords is possible. The reason is that as you vary a point on the circle, the chord through that point and $p$ varies continuously and hence the other intersection with the circle varies continuously, and so their distance varies continuously. Then the intermediate value theorem shows that every intermediate chord length is attained.

Comment: I noticed that Henry just added a reason in his comment; that is another possible parametrization of chords through $p$ and also works (he also uses IVT).

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.I wish I could accept more than one answer...

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: It's okay; my answer is not really complete anyway but was meant to patch the missing arguments in the other answers.